# Forge capture API by Autodesk in my Unity App

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am a unity game developer and I want to create 3d mesh generation from images in my unity App. I found a link of Forge Autodesk
Is it possible with "Reality check API" to implement this.
Any suggestion/SDK will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to generate static assets for your Unity app from photos locally, you could just look at [Autodesk ReCap](https://www.autodesk.com/solutions/photogrammetry-software). The Forge Reality Capture APIs would be useful if you wanted to generate the meshes in the cloud instead. I'm afraid we don't have an SDK for these APIs but you could probably put together a simple bash script using `curl` based on the [official tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/tutorials/create-3d-mesh-from-photos/).